# disconnect event: distinguishing intentional vs timeout

Tags: socket.io

the server-side disconnect event seems to fire whether the disconnect was due to a timeout, or whether it was due to a user leaving a page and the client intentionally sending a disconnect event. Is there a way to distinguish between these two?

Answer (score 1):

I'm on thin ice here, but you should be able to find the reason of the disconnect.

Thats what the [source](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/06e29fef67253de3d0f0755878ed98b53f5ef9f9/lib/namespace.js) is doing:

```
socket.emit('disconnect', packet.reason || 'packet');
```

So check if there is a reason for the disconnect.

Comment: the socket.emit function is when the server is giving data back to the client, isn't it? i'm talking about inside my socket.on("disconnect"...) function being able to distinguish. though looking at the source code it looks like it would be a super simple patch to add this functionality...

Comment: Looks like you were right actually! Its undocumented but the disconnect handler CAN take a `reason` argument. Unfortunately its not documented what possible values it can have...

Answer (score 0):

It's strange these aren't documented, but you can figure them out through trial and error. For example, I get 'forced close' when disconnecting the client and 'transport close' when stopping the server. Timeout might be something else, though.

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(reason) {
  if (reason === 'forced close') {
    console.log('socket was disconnected by client');
  }
  if (reason === 'transport close') {
    console.log('socket was disconnected by server');
  }
  else {
    console.log('socket was disconnected for reason: ' + reason);
  }
});
```